# Flutter doctor does not run successfully

Tags: flutter

I want to create a flutter project and I have installed it.

When I want to check my flutter with `flutter doctor`, I get this error :

[image]

I tried with so many VPN servers and they didn't work. I'm wondering if there is a way to solve this issue.

I also have downloaded the `artifacts.zip` file separately. Can I put my downloaded zip file into any specific address in flutter SDK to solve this issue? Or is there any other way?

I appreciate it if you guys could help me.

Comment: Please donot the attach the link of screenshot instead paste the code or error.